# 3sum(3 sum) if duplicates are allowed

Tags: algorithm

Compared to traditional 3sum problem, where finding all triplets if the summation of any three of the elements equals to zero, we are allowed to use any duplicates. 
e.g., for input array [-2, -1, 3, 4],  (-2, -2, 4) is also a solution. (-2 is duplicated and it's allowed). 
My solution is just making every element to 3 copies and then treat the modified one as the traditional 3sum question. But this approach costs O(2n) space in worst cases. Are there any constant space solution available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is a bit unclear, since you haven't posted your actual implementation. However, assuming [standard O(n^2) implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) without hashing:

```
 sort(S);
 for i=0 to n-3 do
    a = S[i];
    start = i+1;
    end = n-1;
    while (start < end) do
       b = S[start];
       c = S[end];
       if (a+b+c == 0) then
          output a, b, c;
           start = start + 1
           end = end - 1
       else if (a+b+c > 0) then
          end = end - 1;
       else
          start = start + 1;
       end
    end
 end
```

you can get duplicates in your solution by initializing variable `start` to `i` instead of `i+1`. Moreover, if you allow all elements in the final triple to come from the same array element, additionally change while loop condition from `while (start < end)` to `while (start <= end)`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think you are right. We can just modify the `start` to i and add `start <= end` to allow duplicates. BTW, why is my question unclear ? I tried my best to explain this...

Comment: @EmersonXu You are welcome! Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if you consider it useful. Your question would be easier to answer if you posted the actual implementation that you used, because the 3SUM problem could be solved with several different strategies. For example, if you used hashing (which is quite common way to attack this problem), the answer would be different.

Answer (score 0):

### my solution:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    List<List<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList();
    int start1 = 0;
    while (start1 <= nums.length - 1 - 2) {
        int start2 = start1 + 1;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
        while (true) {
            if (start2 >= end) {
                break;
            }
            int result = nums[start1] + nums[start2] + nums[end];
            if (result == 0) {
                addToResponse(resultList, nums[start1], nums[start2], nums[end]);
                do {
                    start2++;
                } while (start2 < end && nums[start2] == nums[start2 - 1]);
                do {
                    end--;
                } while (end > start2 && nums[end] == nums[end + 1]);
            } else if (result > 0) {
                do {
                    end--;
                } while (end > start2 && nums[end] == nums[end + 1]);
            } else if (result < 0) {
                do {
                    start2++;
                } while (start2 < end && nums[start2] == nums[start2 - 1]);
            }


        }
        do {
            start1++;
        }
        while (nums[start1] == nums[start1 - 1] && start1 < nums.length-1);

    }
    return resultList;
}

private static void addToResponse(List<List<Integer>> result, int a, int b, int c) {
    result.add(Arrays.asList(a, b, c));
}
```